# rails routes deals with unexpected id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

Suppose I have some routing as so :

```
resources :projects, path: "/" do
  member do
    get :read
    ....
  end
end
```

in my view (whose url is `/path`) I have a link to `read_project_path(@project)`, which translates into `/path/read`. If I call in my view for `@project.id`, I get the right number, say `some_number`. But, in my `read` controller, `params[:id]` returns `/path` instead of `some_number`. How can it be ?

Comment: The question is too confusing because of `some_thing` & `some_path` can please ask it in a better way

Comment: @AmitThawait I tried to make it more clear, but the fact is that `params[:id]` returns `path` inside the url, which is really weird !

Comment: In your view, what does `read_project_path(@project)` get converted to?

Comment: Have you overriden `to_param` in your `Project`model ? also, are you sure there is an "s" at the end of "resources" in your routes file ?